# Parse value after tag enclosed in parenthesis

Tags: text-processing

I have the following data in a file I am reading into `$p` in a `while` loop. I `grep` the line (`$p`) for `PID`, `APPLTAG`, `UOWLOGDA` and `UOWLOGTI`. When I find the tag present, I want to extract the value in the paren following the tag.

```
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(4C521F5F01501624)
   EXTCONN(414D5143534154322020202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)
   PID(27948)
   APPLTAG(WebSphere MQ Client for Java)
   UOWLOGDA(2020-07-29)                    UOWLOGTI(11.50.30)
```

```
AMQ8276: Display Connection details.
   CONN(4C521F5F9920182E)
   EXTCONN(414D5143534154322020202020202020)
   TYPE(CONN)
   PID(23273)                              APPLTAG(service.core.EnricherMain)
   UOWLOGDA(2020-07-29)                    UOWLOGTI(11.50.46)
```

Comment: Welcome on Ask Ubuntu! How are you going to use the extracted values? E.g. do you just need to print them to the screen? Do you need to put them in shell variables?

Comment: Read `man cut tr`, do something like `| cut '-d(' -f2 | tr -d ')'`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can `grep` just the values with a lookbehind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=PID\(|APPLTAG\(|UOWLOGDA\(|UOWLOGTI\()[^)]+' file
27948
WebSphere MQ Client for Java
2020-07-29
11.50.30
23273
service.core.EnricherMain
2020-07-29
11.50.46
```

- `-P` Perl style regex
- `-o` print the matched pattern only
- `(?<=things)stuff` get the stuff after `things` (lookbehind assertion)
- `\(` the literal opening parenthesis
- `thing1|thing2` alternation - match `thing1` or `thing2`
- `[^)]+` some chars which are not the closing parenthesis

This expression works on your sample, but it may be more reliable to prepend `\b` to the search patterns so they are only caught if they have word breaks (start of line, space, tab etc) before them, in case the same pattern could be the end part of a word. Also, if there is a chance that there may be a matching word followed by an opening parenthesis, with no closing parenthesis, that you do not want to catch, you can explicitly look ahead for the closing one by appending `(?=\))` here to more reliably get only characters between matched parentheses:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\bPID\(|\bAPPLTAG\(|\bUOWLOGDA\(|\bUOWLOGTI\()[^)]+(?=\))'
```

I am not sure whether this approach is adequate for your purpose, though.

Many thanks to fra-san for [suggesting improvements](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1263055/parse-value-after-tag-enclosed-in-parenthesis/1263839#comment2138586_1263839) to this answer :)

Comment: I'd also mention the option of prepending `\b` to the words in the lookbehind assertion and, possibly, appending `(?=\))` to the regular expression to reduce the chances of a false positive.